# How to add an element of derived data to a Django model?

Tags: django

I have a Django Model as follows:

```
class myModel(models.Model): 
    a = models.IntegerField() 
    b = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to add a models.BooleanField() named c to the myModel class. 
However the value of c is simply derived from a and b so I don't want 
it to be stored in the Database.

I want to c to be True if a > b, otherwise False. I want c to reflect 
the correct/current value even when a and b get modifed. And I want to 
be able to access c using myModel.c just like I can access a and b.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Define a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class myModel(models.Model): 
    a = models.IntegerField() 
    b = models.IntegerField() 

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a > self.b
```